# HTML text value didn't display on Modal when pop up

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

written the code below but I fail to display the text value (company) in the Modal. It didn't capture the value of the company name and display on the Modal Pop Up. Can you advise? What is wrong here ? Below is my code

```
<form id="inputform" type="text" method="post">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="company">Company Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ABC Bakers" id="company" readonly>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="prefix">Company Prefix</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1234" id="prefix" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        <label for="InputFile">Product Image input</label>
        <input type="file" id="InputFile" required>
</div><button input type="button" name="btn" value="Submit" id="mybtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit">Submit</button>
```

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Hello</h4></div><div class="modal-body"> 
<h4 id="comp"> </h4>Thank You for your submission! Your. Please check your product information.</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){$("#myBtn").click(function(){
       $("#myModal").modal();
       $("#comp").html($("#company").val());
     });
     $("#myModal").modal("hide").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {        
        location.reload();                   
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two element with same **id**, change one of them to something else.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ABC Bakers" id="company" readonly>
```

```
<h4 id="company"> </h4>
```

And change myBtn click event handler as this:

```
$("#myBtn").click(function () {
    $('#comp').html($('#company').val());
    //$("#myModal").modal();
});
```

And change the id of button to **myBtn**, it's case sensitive.

```
<button input type="button" name="btn" value="Submit" id="myBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I changed to id = comp , still didnt show the company name in the modal pop up. I write the code base on http://jsfiddle.net/nvVBa/76/

Comment: I can't run your code on my computer, it doesn't recognize the modal function. Would you please mention the link to the plugin you have used for modal, or the jQuery version you are using.

Comment: By the way I suggest changing order of two lines in the button event handler, as I updated in my answer.

Comment: you may go to this link http://jsfiddle.net/GINGANK/ukLm5vgd/24 . I change the code but still didnt show the company name in popup

Comment: I checked on jsfiddle, just change the id of button from myBtn to myBtn and it will solve the problem.

And it seems that there is no need for $("#myModal").modal();  in click event.

Also you have to add **value="ABC Bakers"** to compay input, you have added it to source on jsfiddle but not in your original code.

Comment: thank is working now. Thanks. I didnt see the id name is different. Thank a lot